# Stuck on a decoding program

Tags: c++

For my C++ class our latest lab is to write a decoding program like so:

> Write a program to read a file containing an encrypted message, which
>   must be decoded and printed on the screen. Use the following key to
>   decode:   input text :  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz decoded text:
>   iztohndbeqrkglmacsvwfuypjx
>
> That means each 'a' in the input text should be replaced with an 'i',
>   each 'b' with a 'z' and so forth.   Punctuation and space should be
>   kept as is. You will notice that all the letters in the text are
>   lowercase, so the second step will be to fix the captalization. First
>   letter of each sentence should be capitalized.   Print the decoded
>   text to the screen.   You must use an object-oriented approach on this
>   lab. The specification of class Message is given in header file
>   Message.h. You need to implement each of the member functions in the
>   Message.cpp, which you will turn in. The main function is also given
>   so you can test your class, but you don't have to turn it in.   I have
>   added in the class definition in "Message.h" that explain how to
>   implement each member function.   Constructor: Should open the text
>   file and determine its size. To do this, call getFileSize() which is
>   implemented in "Message.h". Check for errors when opening the input
>   file and don't forget to close it at the end. If there is an error,
>   such as the file can't be located, make sure to set length to zero.
>   Otherwise, use the file size to allocate space for message.
>   Destructor: should free the space allocated for message.
>
> decode: decodes the message according to the given key.
>
> fixCapitalization: capitalizes the first letter of each sentence.
>
> dump: prints the content of message on the screen
>
> isEmpty: returns whether message is empty of not.
>
> You only have to turn in message.cpp. You have to make sure it works
>   with the header file that I'm providing, since it will be used to
>   compile your message.cpp.

The header file provided was:

```
class Message
{
private:
char *message;   // holds the message
int length;  // holds the the message length
static const short ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
char code[ALPHABET_SIZE]; // holds the cypher alphabet
      // iztohndbeqrkglmacsvwfuypjx
      // ex: an 'a' in the original message should be converted to 'i', 'b' should be converted to 'z' and so forth

// returns the input file size in bytes
std::streamsize getFileSize(std::fstream &file) const
{
    std::streamsize fsize = 0;
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
    fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg); // moves file pointer back to the beginning
    return fsize;
}
public:
/*
 * This constructor tries to open the file whose name is passed
 * to it in filename. If file opens successfully, calls function
 * getFileSize to determine how many bytes should be allocated
 * for the message. Allocates space for message and reads the
 * content from the file into it. Closes the file at the end.
 * Member variable length should be set to the file size.
 * If file cannot be found, length should be set to zero.
 */
Message(std::string filename);

// The destructor frees the space allocated to message
virtual ~Message();

// Decodes the message
void decode();

// Capitalizes first letter in each sentence
void fixCapitalization();

// Prints the content of message on the screen
void dump() const;

// Returns true if the message is empty
bool isEmpty() const;
};
```

What I'm really stuck on is how to use a constructor to open the file, and read the size of it.
I can't even figure out how to open the file with the constructor at all. 
I tried to use ifstream in my constructor like so:

**Edited 2/24/17 10:36 a.m.:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "Message.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
// create a message object with the content of Encrypted.txt
Message m ("Encrypted.txt");

if (m.isEmpty())
{
  std::cout << "Could not read message";
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
std::cout << "Original message: " << std::endl;
m.dump();
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
m.decode();
m.fixCapitalization();
std::cout << "Decoded message: " << std::endl;
m.dump();
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
Message::Message(std::string filename)
{
fstream infile;
infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
// read contents
// close the file
if (!infile)
{
    length=0;
}else
{
// getFileSize and allocate so much space for message
    std::streamsize length = getFileSize(infile);
    message = new char[length + 1];
//copy contents from file to message
for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++)
    {
        infile >> new char[i];
    }
}
infile.close();
}

Message::~Message()
{

}

void Message::decode()
{

}

void Message::fixCapitalization()
{

}

void Message::dump() const
{
cout << message;
}

bool Message::isEmpty() const
{
if (length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }else
return false;
}
```

This is what I've put together so far. When I run the program it tells me "Could not read message" so I assume that the file was not opened properly. Can someone check over my code for me and tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
char *message = new char;
*message = message[length];
```

allocates space for *one* `char`, and then reads the invalid location `message[length]`, which is undefined.

You need to allocate `length + 1` characters.

I would write it like this:

```
Message::Message(std::string filename)
    : message(nullptr),
      length(0)
{
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    if (infile)
    {
        length = getFileSize(infile);
        message = new char[length + 1];
        // ...
    }
}
```

The destructor of `std::ifstream` takes care of closing the stream if it was open, so you don't need to do that by hand. (Tell your teacher about this; they seem to be stuck in a C mindset.)

Side note: a more useful `getFileSize` would restore the previous read position and not assume that it was at the beginning:

```
std::streamsize getFileSize(std::fstream &file) const
{
    std::streamsize old_pos = file.tellg();
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
    std::streamsize fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg (old_pos, std::ios::beg); // moves file pointer back to the previous position
    return fsize;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that. Do you happen to know why I am getting the "Launch failed. Binary not found." error?

Comment: @A.huy Probably because whatever IDE you're using couldn't find the program, possibly because compilation or linking failed. It's impossible to say for sure from here.

Comment: I think the linking failed, but I don't know how to fix that. This is the full message: "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

Comment: @A.huy There should be a message about which symbols are missing somewhere.

Comment: Hi sorry to be a bother, but could you check my edit from the original post? I feel like I'm close but I'm still missing something

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
Message::Message(std::string filename)  
{  
    std::ifstream infile;  
    infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
    // read contents & initialize other member variables.
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        // getFileSize and allocate so much space for message
        length = getFileSize(infile);
        message = new char[length + 1];
        //copy contents from file to message              
    }
    // close the file finally 
    infile.close()
}
```

**EDIT for usage**

```
int main () {
    Message m("Encrypted.txt");
    // other operations on m
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I tried that, eclipse gave me an error message saying that the member declaration was not found.

Comment: Update your declaration like this `Message(const std::string& filename);` in the header file

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the header file, is there anyway I can get it to work without adjusting the header?

Comment: Then just add this `infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);` in your constructor definition and remove `infile.open("Encrypted.txt");` from your previous definition. Finally, while creating `Message`object, pass `"Encrypted.txt"` as an argument

Comment: I'm still receiving a member error definition error

Comment: "Member declaration not found"

Comment: -out-of-line definition of 'Message' does not match any declaration in 'Message'

Comment: You need to pass an argument in `Message` like `Message m("Encrypted.txt");`

Comment: 'Message::Message(string& filename)
    {
 Message m("Encrypted.txt");
 std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
    }'  Is this correct?

Comment: I think that was a good start but now it's giving me a yellow error saying that the "member 'message' was not initialized in this constructor"

Comment: when you read the contents of the file inside the constructor, you have to store that information in your member variable `message`

Comment: `Message::Message(std::string filename)  
{  
 message = 0;  
    fstream infile;  
    infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);  
    // read contents  
    // close the file  
    if (!infile)  
    {  
     length=0;  
    }else  
    {  
     length = getFileSize(infile);  
     char *message = new char;  
     *message = message[length];  
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  
     {  
      infile >> message[i];  
     }  
    }  
    infile.close();  
    `

Comment: Okay, now I've got an error that says "Launch failed. Binary not found." when trying to run the program. I think i've had this error the whole time though, it's keeping me from running and testing my program. Do you happen to know what's causing this?

Comment: Hey sorry for bothering you but could you check my edit from the original post? I feel like I'm almost there

Comment: You need to do `length = getFileSize(infile);` in your constructor rather than declaring a new variable `length`